# Windows XAMPP issue: The site ahead contains malware

Tags: php, windows, apache, xampp, virtualhost

I am just setting up `virtualhost` in xampp on windows. I edit the file `D:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf` and add this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost.myproject.com
  DocumentRoot "D:\virtualdomain\MyProject"
  SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development
  <Directory "D:\virtualdomain\MyProject">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
  </Directory>
  ServerName localhost.myproject.com
  ErrorLog "localhost.myproject.com"
  CustomLog "localhost.myproject.com" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Then i edit the file `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` and add this

```
127.0.0.1       localhost.myproject.com
```

Inside the directory `D:\virtualdomain\MyProject` i created one file `index.php`. But when i am trying to access the `http://localhost.myproject.com/index.php`, It will give me this error page
[image: Error Page]